# index.html tries to resolve css files from root URI

Tags: html, css, angular

I just built my angular 11+ app and put the generated files inside my `www/` folder.

- I already have a website running at the root of `www`
- So I just put my files inside a subfolder `www/second-site`

When accessing `https://my-domain.com/second-site` I'm getting some errors on the console

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://my-site.com/styles.b571ddf4692cab415961.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

It tries to get the `styles.css` from the root, but it should try to resolve from `https://my-site.com/second-side`
Is this an angular misconfiguration or should I edit my nginx config? I'm kinda confused

Comment: Declare second-site as base href in your index.html

Comment: @Romain Have you solved this?

Comment: @ZamAbdulVahid yes. I had to define the base-href in my angular config